# Will Google Play Search URL count as organic traffic for my app?

Tags: seo, google-adsense, android

Will Google Play Search URL count as organic traffic for my app? Like this (https://play.google.com/store/search?q=keywordofmyapp&c=apps), if I paste this URL on my website and it leads users to download my app from Google Play. (When user will click on this URL from mobile, it will open google play and perform a search and in that search result my app will be on the top and user will download it from there). I want the answer with relevant to admob as well. Because google has restricted my app saying (app traffic is being assessed). And someone told me that try to build organic traffic to solve this problem.

Comment: I'm on the fence as to whether this question is on-topic here or not. Questions here have to be about your website. This question involves marketing your Android app through your website. But the main focus is on play store optimization, which isn't website related.

Comment: Can you tell me any proper platform for this question. Earlier i asked on stack overflow they referred me to this platform to ask the question. I badly need an answer about it.

Comment: I left it open here for now. I doubt that any of our regulars will know the answer though, because we are experts with websites and have little experience with mobile apps or the play store.

Comment: Cross-posted to Android.SE: https://android.stackexchange.com/q/245606/44325 (but off-topic since that site focuses on end-users problems, not developers)